# OnSaveInstanceState/ RestCalls

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask, singleton, runnable

I am relatively new to Android development, and I have a question about onSaveInstanceState(). I am currently working on a login Activity for an app. To check to see if the user can login to their account, I perform a rest call to a server and, based on the response-code, see if I should grant access to the user. The root of my question is based on the fact that I am trying to avoid passing the Activity's Context to my rest-call class. To do this, I create a boolean field in my login Activity representing whether or not the rest-call was successful and a runnable that updates said boolean that I pass to the rest-call class. I know this goes against the idea of an AsyncTask, but I can't find any alternative to simply putting up a dialog box telling the user to wait while this happens. My questions are below.

1) If I use savedInstanceState() in the onCreate method, how do I instantiate this boolean field for the first time barring null checking an Object boolean? What I mean by this is that after the Activity is destroyed for whatever reason (such as orientation change, etc...) I will use the boolean value stored in my overriden onSaveInstanceState method; however, when it is created for the first time, it has no reference to a boolean value so it has to create one.

2) Does this Runnable even help? I did it so that I wouldn't have to pass the context, but if the Activity is going to be deleted before the RestCall(AsyncTask) is complete, does it really matter whether you pass the context or a Runnable affecting a field of the Activity? The more I think about this, the more I believe it is not going to make much of a difference as it will still result in it pointing to a non-existent object. I am trying to avoid using a Singleton design as I have gathered it is not optimal, but because of the potential lag in time with an AsyncTask, I am beginning to think that it may not be avoidable.

I know onSaveInstanceState() is a topic that has been brought up a lot on StackOverflow, however, I could not find an answer to these questions. I apologize if there has already been a thread for this, but any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Login Activities' setup:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText username_et;
private EditText password_et;
private Button login_b;
private boolean login_success = true;
private Runnable run;


/**
 * Instances created when app starts
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_login);
//  login_success = false;
    login_success = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("login_success");
    username_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_text);
    username_et.setOnClickListener(LoginActivity.this);
    password_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);
    password_et.setOnClickListener(LoginActivity.this);
    login_b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login_b.setOnClickListener(LoginActivity.this);
    run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            login_success = true;
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("login_success", login_success);
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you not using the `AsyncTask` from android? It has everything you need and you can even pass a callback if you need more control over the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations. You just discovered Android's dirty little secret.

`AsyncTask` has an inherent design flaw.  It doesn't deal well with configuration changes that happen during background task execution because of exactly the problem you mentioned. It needs to hold a reference to the activity, but there's no guarantee that the reference will still be valid by the time the background task completes.

Here are two ways to overcome this problem:

1. I refer you to [Alex Lockwood's excellent blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) on using hidden fragments with `setRetainInstance(true)` to span activity destruction and recreation.  This is a more involved solution than the next one, but this solution has the advantage that you can still report progress with callbacks.  If you were intending to call `publishProgress()` in your `AsyncTask`, then this is the method you should use.
2. Use a `Loader`.  Loaders were designed around database data retrieval in the background, but the fact is that they can also be used to handle remote server access in the background as well.  I use a `Loader` for the majority of my remote server tasks.

   Here's an example:

   ```
   public static class ResetPasswordLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Pair<CharSequence, Exception>> {

       private static final String TAG = "ResetPasswordLoader ";

       private String mEmail;

       public ResetPasswordLoader(Context context, String email) {
           super(context);
           mEmail = email;
           // set the content-changed flag
           onContentChanged();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onStartLoading() {

           // only start the load if the content-changed flag is set
           // takeContentChanged() returns the value of the flag before it is cleared
           if (takeContentChanged()) {
               forceLoad();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public Pair<CharSequence, Exception> loadInBackground() {

           CharSequence result = null;
           Exception exc = null;
           try {
               result = Service.getInstance().resetPassword(mEmail);
           } catch (RemoteServiceException e) {
               exc = e;
               Log.e(TAG, "loadInBackground(), email = " + mEmail, e);
           }

           return new Pair<>(result, exc);
       }
   }
   ```

   Also, in my `onLoadFinished()` override I make sure to call `loaderManager.destroyLoader()` on the loader's id.

   Again, Alex Lockwood's blog has some great articles on loaders as well.

For the UI, something I do frequently is put up a indeterminate progress bar over the UI upon calling `loaderManager.initLoader()`.  I also set a boolean like `mProgressShown`.  This boolean gets saved in `onSaveInstanceState`, so when the activity/fragment is created again, I restore the boolean value which tells me to show the progress bar immediately.  Some time later `onLoadFinished` will be called and I clear `mProgressShown` and hide the progress bar.

Comment: Thank You! This is exactly what I needed!